# OOP for data analysis

Tags: python, oop

I know that there are already many questions about OOP, but I am still not sure if it makes sense for me and how to use it properly. I often reuse code and modify it , when I write a new code to analyze different stuff from different files. 
I use Python 2.7.13 to analyze data, my code contains typically about 350 lines
and is always structured like this pseudocode:

```
def read_files():
    read data_file_1.txt
    read data_file_2.txt
    read info_file_1.txt
    save_everything to data_list

def calculate_crazy_stuff_step1():

def calculate_crazy_stuff_step2():

def calculate_crazy_stuff_step3():

def calculate_and_plot():
    read data_list
    calculate_crazy_stuff_step1()
    calculate_crazy_stuff_step2()
    calculate_crazy_stuff_step3()
    save_everything to result_list

def write_results():
    write result_list to resultfile.txt

def main():
     data=read_files()
     open result_file
     for n in range (len(number_of_files)):
         calculate_and_plot(data)
         write_results(result_list)
     result_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

If you have any suggestions if it makes sense to use OOP here and how to apply to this code please tell me. At some point I also might want to have a GUI, put my analysis code together and control with the GUI what to analyze, but I thought the first step is to have a well structured code.

Comment: If you have *working* code, and want a review of that, then the place to post is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your pseudo is too broad, presumably "saving to data list" means you have to read another file again which just seems like madness to me when you read it n times in the next line of code

Comment: This really isn't an example of spaghetti code. OOP is one approach to organizing code. It isn't the only one.

Comment: Typically I read about 20 to 30 files with about 1500 entries and don't care so much about performance. The most time consuming part is always saving the plots (if I plot). But Indeed I could move the read_files to the for loop.

Comment: This looks like a memory nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: What you show has **nothing** to do with **OOP**?

Comment: Not yet, thats why I asked the question. @Mast: If my code uses 500Mb of Memory that is not yet a memory nightmare. However i will probably change it

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga : I edited my question, because of you comment. The spaghetti part is hidden at the moment in the calculate_and_plot(). Actually I currently dont have sub-functions there, but if I dont use OOP I would do it like the code example. I was just wondering how my code structure could look like if I would use OOP.